# DPC latency issue

Tags: latency, dpc

My Asus ROG laptop (i7-6700HQ, GTX960M, 8GB DDR4, 1TB Samsung 850Evo SATA SSD, Win10 64bit) has been painfully slow, sometimes at its worst even slightly moving the mouse takes 5 seconds. Playing youtube videos can be impossible as well, at best the video is behind the audio, and at worst both video and audio crack all the time.

A friend suggested it might be a DPC latency issue and suggested I use diagnostics tools. Here are the results, I sorted the LatencyMon result based on the highest total execution time. The highest 2 drivers are ndis.sys and tcpip.sys

DPC Latency Checker:

[image]

LatencyMon:

[image]

What can I do? It's getting ridiculous, to the point of the laptop becoming unusable.

Comment: You linked to the same image twice.

Comment: I wonder if this might be related to your chipset drivers - namely your SATA controller. Try Uninstalling the "IDE ATA\ATAPI controllers" device relating to your SATA controller -> restart the machine -> let Windows re-install the driver -> test.

Comment: whoops, copied the wrong link, fixed!

Comment: well, if we presume this is a DPC problem, then the obvious culprit is the top one in the sorted list by an order of magnitude. Do what DPC checker suggests and disable the network interface.